# log4net не ведет логи при создании инсталятора

Tags: c#, windows-service, log4net

Есть проект `windows service`, в котором должно быть логирование. Используется log4net. Если я устанавливаю службу через `installutil.exe` . Тогда все прекрасно работает, логи пишутся. Добавил инсталлятор для установки службы (имеется в виду windows setup), служба запускается, работает, но не зависимо от debug или release сборки, логи не ведутся вообще.

Кусок конфига:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="ConnectionInfo" type="Astra.Common.Configuration.ConnectionInfoConfiguration, Astra.Common" />
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net, Version=2.0.8, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" />
  </configSections>
```

....

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="Logs\service.log" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d  %-5p %m%n" />
      </layout>

    </appender>

    <logger name="LOGGER">
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </logger>
  </log4net>
```

Класс

```
public static class Logger
    {
        private static ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("LOGGER");


        public static ILog Log
        {
            get { return log; }
        }

        public static void InitLogger()
        {
            XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        }

        static Logger()
        {
            InitLogger();
        }
    }
```

В асембли

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

Не понимаю что не так, но после установки через инсталятор , логи не пишутся, хотя библиотека log4net попадает в пакет установки.

Есть какие-то идеи ?

Служба работает в режиме NetworkService и права админа для записи у нее есть

Comment: У вас задан относительный каталог — а в каком месте собираются писаться логи? Какой у вас рабочий каталог (он не обязательно совпадает с каталогом программы)? Попробуйте для отладки указать абсолютный каталог. (И дать всем права на запись.)

Comment: @VladD Спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: @VladD к сожалению не помогло

Comment: проверьте заодно наличие и доступность файлов конфигурации, при  запуске в режиме службы бывают сюрпризы. Также попробуйте запустить с правами локальной системы, чтобы исключить нехватку прав.

Comment: Вопрос актуален?